# Not Able to Set SEEN flag to mails read from gmail

Tags: java, gmail, imap

I am using IMAP protocol to connet to my gmail account.

My application fails at this line.
**message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);**

And the log details are as follows:

```
[java] ---- exception report ----------------------------------------------------------
 [java] An error Occured while reading mail
 [java] Exception: javax.mail.MessagingException
 [java] Message: A10 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
 [java] ---- cause ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] Exception: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException
 [java] Message: A10 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
 [java] ---- stack trace ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [java] com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A10 NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
 [java] com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:294)
 [java] com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1294)
 [java] com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1279)
 [java] com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.setFlags(IMAPMessage.java:843)
 [java] javax.mail.Message.setFlag(Message.java:565)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kumaraswamy.N

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you opened your folder as READ_ONLY. Make sure you are doing

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
```

when you open your folder.

BTW POP protocol doesn't recognize Flags. So I'm surprised it works for POP since you should be getting an IllegalWriteException when using POP. Regardless, **message.setFlag(...)** won't do anything with POP.

Answer (score 0):

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
```

This is a writ operation which you are performing on your code.

As @Nikordaris said  give writ permission like this:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
```